# How to draw the graph of $f(x)=\int_0^x\left(\frac{t^3-2t^2-4}{t^2+1}\right)\ dt$ using only your calculator?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$f(x)=\int_0^x\left(\frac{t^3-2t^2-4}{t^2+1}\right)\ dt$$
I need to find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts, and the inflection points of the function $f(x)$ (with both $x$ and $y$ coordinates). I need to find it through the calculator and explain my answer. How do I find the antiderivative?

Comment: Drawing with a calculator is rather tedious, even for expert mathematicians, pencil or pen is usually recommended for best results.

Comment: Is it antiderivative or derivative? Thanks.

Comment: @jnh I think the OP wanted an anti-derivative, not the derivative ...

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking :)

Comment: @Gamamal I don't know about that. I find graphing calculators to be pretty efficient ;)

Comment: in the ti-83, you can put this function in $y1 = FnInt((T^3-2T^2-4)/(T^2+1), T, 0, x)$ set the $x$ window ,not too big, $[-1,1]$ and $y$ window $[-2,2]$. it will graph it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already have how to calculate the integral explicitly from Olivier. However you can find the maximums and minimums with the fundamental theorem of calculus together with finding zeros to the polynomial $t^3 - 2t^2 - 4$. At least one $t$ root is easy to guess and then continue with polynomial division and completing the square.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You may observe that, by partial fraction decomposition, you have
$$
\frac{t^3-2t^2-4}{t^2+1}=t-2-\frac{t+2}{t^2+1}
$$ giving, for the antiderivative that vanishes at $x=0$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{t^3-2t^2-4}{t^2+1}dt&=\int_0^x\left(t-2-\frac{t+2}{t^2+1}\right)dt\\\\
&=\int_0^x\left(t-2\right)dt-\int_0^x\frac{t}{t^2+1}dt-2\int_0^x\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}2-2x-\frac12\ln(x^2+1)- 2\arctan x.
\end{align}
$$
**Remark.** Here the constant of integration is equal to $0$ since $ \int_0^x$ is equal to $0$ when $x=0$.

Comment: Don't forget the integration constant. ;) Or maybe you meant it was trivial to calculate and left it as an exercise?

Comment: @mathreadler Here, the integration constant is equal to $0$. Do you see why? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I see why, as when x = 0 f must be 0 and then you can evaluate the expression at the end for x = 0 which also is 0. But I thought maybe it would be good to explicitly write it for newbies.

Comment: Thanks. Without transition, I've camped in a park at Linkoping:nice memory.